# Saving individual plots for each category in a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

My dataframe looks like this:

```
counts  labels   event_date
6208    label1   2021-07-02
324     label1   2021-07-03    
8       label1   2021-07-04
7298    label2   2021-07-02
3       label2   2021-07-03    
5       label2   2021-07-05
```

There are 100s of labels with daily event data and when I plot all of them on a multi-line chart its hard to interpret it.

Here is my code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, facecolor='#293952')
sns.lineplot(data=df_labels, x='event_date', y='counts', hue='labels', color='#FDAC53', linewidth=2.5)
plt.savefig(label_chart_name, dpi = 100)
```

where sns is the seaborn alias and plt is matplotlib.pyplot

[image: not a useful chart]

I can iterate through the dataframe and create individual dataframe for each label type and save a single-line chart but is there a better way to do this?
If so how do I do it?

Comment: Not sure there is better way to do that. To limit computation, make sure you don't actually plot each figure when iterating.  You can also consider plotting your data as a [heat map](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

in a jupyter notebook--

```py
(df
 .pivot_table(rows='event_date', columns='labels', values='counts', agg_func=sum)
 .plot()
)
```